# Updating Text in UI from Async Task using onProgressUpdate

Tags: android

I am using `AsyncTask` to do a http request. But the code is crashing while trying to update UI elements.

```
class ServerRequest extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
    private  View rootView;
    private Activity rootAct;
    private String result;
    public ServerRequest(View view,Activity act) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub\
        rootView = view;
        rootAct = act;
    }
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String URL=params[0];
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        String responseString="DEFAULT";

        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(URL));
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                out.close();
                responseString = out.toString();

                //..more logic
            } else{
                //Closes the connection.
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        result = responseString;
        publishProgress(responseString);
        return  responseString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        EditText tt = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.codeResult);
        tt.setText("Sample Text"); //Causing APP TO CRASH
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d("retval",result);
    }
}
```

The `setText` in `onProgressUpdate` is causing my application to crash. I have gone through most of the threads on this but couldn't find a solution.

LOG

```
12-27 18:32:00.163: E/AndroidRuntime(24685):    at com.trueeduc.qrcode.ServerRequest.onProgressUpdate(ServerRequest.java:1)
12-27 18:32:00.163: E/AndroidRuntime(24685):    at com.trueeduc.qrcode.ServerRequest.onProgressUpdate(ServerRequest.java:69)
12-27 18:32:00.163: E/AndroidRuntime(24685):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:647)
12-27 18:32:00.163: E/AndroidRuntime(24685):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-27 18:32:23.253: E/AndroidRuntime(24801):    at com.trueeduc.qrcode.ServerRequest.onProgressUpdate(ServerRequest.java:69)
12-27 18:32:23.253: E/AndroidRuntime(24801):    at com.trueeduc.qrcode.ServerRequest.onProgressUpdate(ServerRequest.java:1)
12-27 18:32:23.253: E/AndroidRuntime(24801):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:647)
12-27 18:35:00.233: E/AndroidRuntime(24888):    at com.trueeduc.qrcode.ServerRequest.onProgressUpdate(ServerRequest.java:69)
12-27 18:35:00.233: E/AndroidRuntime(24888):    at com.trueeduc.qrcode.ServerRequest.onProgressUpdate(ServerRequest.java:1)
12-27 18:35:00.233: E/AndroidRuntime(24888):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:647)
12-27 18:35:00.233: E/AndroidRuntime(24888):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-27 19:02:05.643: E/AndroidRuntime(25128):    at com.trueeduc.qrcode.ServerRequest.onProgressUpdate(ServerRequest.java:69)
12-27 19:02:05.643: E/AndroidRuntime(25128):    at com.trueeduc.qrcode.ServerRequest.onProgressUpdate(ServerRequest.java:1)
12-27 19:02:05.643: E/AndroidRuntime(25128):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:647)
12-27 19:02:05.643: E/AndroidRuntime(25128):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-27 19:02:22.373: E/AndroidRuntime(25192):    at com.trueeduc.qrcode.ServerRequest.onProgressUpdate(ServerRequest.java:69)
12-27 19:02:22.373: E/AndroidRuntime(25192):    at com.trueeduc.qrcode.ServerRequest.onProgressUpdate(ServerRequest.java:1)
12-27 19:02:22.373: E/AndroidRuntime(25192):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:647)
12-27 19:02:22.373: E/AndroidRuntime(25192):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
```

Comment: why don't you set the textview on onPostExcexute() ....

Comment: Are you call this function in Fragment.?

Comment: No I am calling it from Main UI thread like this:
        ServerRequest req = new ServerRequest(view,this);
        req.execute(URL);

Comment: but it always crashing. Change  EditText text = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.codeResult);

Comment: Have you tried setting the textview on onPostExcecute() ??

Comment: I have tried onPostExecute() also. Same problem.

@piyush view will not be defined in my scope. I am setting rootView = view in constructor.

Comment: can you please post of logcat of crash

Comment: Log posted on main post

Comment: rootView or EditText tt may be null?

Comment: @aegean OK I will check that. What do you recommend If I want to update a text in Main UI. Passing the View or the TextView?

Comment: where did you inflate rootView ???

Comment: I passed the view in the constructor and set rootView to view. Do I need to inflate.

@aegean Ya it was null.

Comment: what exception is thrown

Comment: There is no exception in this LOG. Post the full log with exception and everything. It looks like your `EditText` object is Null.

Comment: Ya the EditText object was null. Thanks all for guiding me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EditText object was null. After that it started working. Thanks for your guidelines to figure out the problems

Answer (score 4):

i think its because you are not referencing the activity,whose `EditText` you want to use in `AsyncTask`,so i made some changes in your code,update your code with this:

```
class ServerRequest extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
    private  View rootView;
    private Activity rootAct;
    private String result;
    public ServerRequest(View view,Activity act) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub\
        rootView = view;
        rootAct = act;
    }
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String URL=params[0];
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        String responseString="DEFAULT";

        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(URL));
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                out.close();
                responseString = out.toString();

                //..more logic
            } else{
                //Closes the connection.
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        result = responseString;
        publishProgress(responseString);
        return  responseString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        //updated this line
        EditText tt = (EditText) act.findViewById(R.id.codeResult);
        tt.setText("Sample Text"); //Causing APP TO CRASH
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d("retval",result);
    }
}
```